# createWork called multiple times when using OneTimeWorkRequest and enqueueUniqueWork method

Tags: android, rx-java, android-workmanager

In Splash Activity onCreate method, I have used WorkManager with OneTimeWorkRequest and enqueueUniqueWork() method. My worker class is child of RxWorker class and I have override "fun createWork(): Single" method of it.

So in the production app, I can see some crashes in firebase report of kind:
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
Too many receivers, total of 1000, registered for pid: 1495, callerPackage: com.ril.ajio

and

Caused by android.os.DeadSystemException
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService

whose logs say that multiple calls to createWork() method even though I have used the enqueueUniqueWork() method and it is in Splash Activity onCreate method so enqueueUniqueWork() will get called once.

Can't find a way to debug this issue as I can't replicate on my side. I am using 2.5.0 version work manager.

Comment: Can you add to your question the code you use to enqueue your `WorkRequest`? Which [`ExistingWorkPolicy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy) are you using?

Comment: I am using ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP. @pfmaggi